# Use list comprehension to identify elements in a list of words which contains all specified letters?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a piece of list comprehension that identifies all words containing all specified letters.

I have a function which takes a list of words (words) and a list of letters,

```
def words_with_letters(words, letters):
    words_letters = list(letters)
    #This would return ['t', 'e', 's', 't']
```

What I then want to do is to identify all words in my list of words(words variable) that contains the letters from the letters variable (in this case, test).

Right now I have the following code,

```
    test = [word for word in words if (letter for letter in words_letters) in word]
```

Where I am saying to cycle through each element of words and return them IF each letter specified (words_letters) is in that word.

Unfortunately, I think I need a slight tweak but can't understand where I have gone wrong. I believe it's in the (letter for letter in words_letters) portion where I am trying to cycle through each letter required,

```
words_with_letters(words, 'test')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use the boolean expression `all` in such manner `[word for word in words if all(letter in word for letter in words_letters)]` but it will miss whether letters have one or multiple occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the bult-in  [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) function in a list comprehension.

```
def words_with_letters(words, letters):
    return [word for word in words if all(letter in word for letter in letters)]

words = ['word1', 'wtoersdt2', 'word3']

print(words_with_letters(words, 'test'))  # -> ['wtoersdt2']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `set` difference with `list_comprehension` to see the matches like below

```
words =  ["test_word1","tst_word2","word3_test","word4"]
letters = ['t','e','s','t']

match= [word for word in words if len(list(set(letters)-set(word)))==0]
print(match)
#will return ['test_word1', 'word3_test'] only
```